# Need to scroll to bottom whenever a new div is added at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on a chatbot, need to scroll to the bottom whenever a new element is added, working with jquery

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried? Take a look at the [`element.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) JavaScript method.

Comment: scrollTo is not ideal for all browsers.
also scrolltop is always returning 0 and couldn't value for scrollTop.

Comment: Without seeing your code or knowing your requirements, there's no way I can 1) recommend a solution that'll work across all browsers you need 2) debug why `scrollTop` is not working for you. Feel free to post code in your question and I'd be happy to help further.

Comment: found the issue for scrollTop returning zero, it was because height was set 100%, now that has been fixed. now when i auto scroll it, it gives bounce feel, not smoothly going, 
$('.scl-d').animate({scrollTop: $('.scl-d').scrollTop()+$('.msg-wrapper').children().last().height()}, 800);

Answer (score 0):

It has been asked before but I'm not sure that in this context

[**Here is an Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/3jxeqzm6/)

**Here is the code:**

```
$("button#add-row").on("click",function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>");
  var $doc = $('html,body');
    $doc.animate({scrollTop: $doc.height()}, 500);
});
```

As you can see `$doc.animate({scrollTop: $doc.height()}, 500)` the jQuery `animate` has property called `scrollTop` which its value (the height of the document) is setting the scroll position.

In the Example I'm calling it whenever a button is pushed but you can easily add it to your chat-bot response callback.

You should improve this by blocking new animation firing before the previous one has ended - But this is another topic.

```js
$("button#add-row").on("click",function(){
 $("ul").append("<li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>");
  var $doc = $('html,body');
 $doc.animate({scrollTop: $doc.height()}, 500);
});
```

```css
ul {
  width:80%;
  margin:0;
}
li {
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:20px;
}
button {
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-row">
Add a new row
</button>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: scrolltop is always returning 0 and couldn't value for scrollTop. tried scrolltop for all, window, document, seperate div, html, body. nothing seems to be working, scrolltop is not scrolling, not working on my site, but working on other sites, so browser is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this it demonstrate a simulation of the solution you are expecting.

```js
//Event listener which triggers when a DOM is inserted in the #parent Div
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {

  //if you need details about the DOM
  console.log(event)

  //Scroll to the bottom using this
  $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());

});

function addDiv() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#parent').html('<div class="some-div"><label>You have been Scrolled! :P</label></div>');
    console.log('Div added')
  })
}

//Execute a method after 3 seconds to simulate a new div added in the body
setTimeout(addDiv, 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!-- This is just to create a div so that we scroll to the bottom -->
  <div style="height:1000px">
  </div>
  <!-- Main div for your chatbot to which new divs will be added -->
  <div id="parent"></div>
</body>
```

> Attaching a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eah837md/60/) for reference

Comment: scrolltop is always returning 0 and couldn't value for scrollTop. tried scrolltop for all, window, document, seperate div, html, body. nothing seems to be working, scrolltop is not scrolling, not working on my site, but working on other sites, so browser is not the problem